# How did the non-Asgardian children came to be New Asgard residents?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-love-and-thunder

In *Thor: Love and Thunder*, it was revealed that there were several non-Asgardian children that are living in New Asgard. They, along with the Asgardian children, end up getting kidnapped by Gorr.

Relevant dialogue:

> **Thor:** Hey, don't forget you're Asgardian kids.
> **Lycan kid:** I'm not. I'm just a Lycan kid.
> **Midassian kid:** And I'm a Midassian kid.
> **Falligarian kid:** I'm Falligarian.
> **Thor:** Okay, okay. But today, you're Asgardians.

I didn't remember seeing the non-Asgardian children in *Thor: Ragnarok*, so I first thought that they were the children of the gladiators from Sakaar that traveled with the Asgardians in *Ragnarok*. Upon rewatching *Ragnarok*, I noticed that only [Roscoe](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Roscoe) (masked gladiator that looks like a human), Korg, and Miek were shown to be alive at the end. (Roscoe ends up dead in *Avengers: Infinity War* later.) If I'm not mistaken, out of all the gladiators from Sakaar, only Korg and Miek were revealed to have survived Thanos' attack on their spacecraft in *Infinity War*. In the New Asgard scenes in *Avengers: Endgame*, these children nor non-Asgardians that look like them weren't shown. I also did not see the parents of the non-Asgardian children (nor any non-human and non-Asgardian adults, aside from Korg, Miek, and Gorr) in the New Asgard scenes in *Love and Thunder*. It seems that the non-Asgardian children in New Asgard are living apart from their parents.

##### Where did the non-Asgardian children come from? How did they come to be New Asgard residents?

Here are screencaps of some of the non-Asgardian children. Notice that they don't look like the gladiators from Sakaar as shown in *Ragnarok*. Some of the non-Asgardians shown are: a fanged hairy child that looks like a monkey (the Lycan kid), a green-skinned child, a red-skinned child, a gold-skinned & gold-haired child (the Midassian kid), and a blue-skinned child with protrusions on their head.

[image: screencap of kidnapped children from New Asgard by Gorr]
[image][image]
[image][image]
[image][image]

Comment: It wasn't only Korg and MIek that survived. 50% of the Asgardians escaped. That presumably includes 50% of the gladiators.

Comment: @Valorum I've rewatched *Ragnarok*.  Only Roscoe, Korg, and Miek were shown to have survived. (Roscoe ends up dead in *Infinity War*.) Were there off-screen survivors in *Ragnarok*?

Comment: Valkyrie, for one. And all the other Asgardians

Comment: @Valorum I'm only talking about the *non-Asgardians* in this question. Were there off-screen *non-Asgardian* survivors aside from Korg and Miek, in *Ragnarok* or *Infinity War*? On-screen, only Korg and Miek were revealed to have survived.

Comment: And some enormous dude; https://comicbook.com/marvel/news/avengers-endgame-mystery-creature-new-asgard-gladiator/

Comment: The non-human children are presumably alien refugees offered a place of safety by the Guardians of the Galaxy.

Answer (score 1):

*"Asgard is not a place, it is its people."* - Odin; Thor Ragnarok.

Between this movie and Love and Thunder, Thor goes through quite a development; moreso even than from when he first appeared in Thor - At first he was a proud, narcissistic hothead, but by the time he reaches this point, he has learned that he serves the people, not the other way around.

By this point in his story, he has lost his father, his mother, and his brother (twice now, I believe?), his girlfriend, and now Hela is threatening to take his kingdom from him.

By the end of the movie, he has lost his home town as well, so all he has left is the people in his life - Valkyrie, Loki (who he now has trust issues with at this point), Hulk, Korg, and what's left of the people of Asgard.

And then, by the end of Infinity War, he has lost his brother (for real this time?), and half of the universe, who he was trying to protect. So when we see him at the beginning of Endgame, I would dare say he's holding on to what little he has left, and is likely wanting to make up for the mistakes he's made that led to his failures.

The point that screams at me by this point in Thor's development is that if someone is losing everyone, he would want to make sure others never feel his pain.

So by the time *Love and Thunder* comes around, Thor has overcome his grief, has been travelling around with the Guardians of the Galaxy, and I daresay would probably continue to harbor refugees, offering them a place to rebuild, in New Asgard.

Answer (score -3):

Remember that Asgardians are really just aliens, with the "gods" being their version of a standard Marvel mutant through blood. Since New Asgard is known as a home for humanoid aliens, it can be easily be inferred that other lost aliens came there for refuge since they would feel a sense of belonging there with other people who don't exactly "fit in" with the rest of humanity.

Comment: "*other lost aliens came there for refuge*" Was this revealed in other MCU media?

Comment: @galacticninja, key-word is infer. It's just an informed guess. To be fully honest though, the diversity in the species of the kids is probably just an art choice by the director and supporting team. I really don't think there's an absolute answer. Could be some of the gladiators, could be lost or abandoned aliens, or maybe the Asgardians were hiding some wild genes.

Answer (score -3):

Some of them might be Thors illegitimate love-children.

At the start or the film, during the narrated montage, Thor is shown having relations with a blue haired swashbuckler and then a wolf-woman (on top of a woman wolf). It just might be coincidence but one of the children has blue hair and one is a Lycan.

Comment: That is more likely to be false than true. None of those children have acknowledged Thor as their father, nor did Thor acknowledge any of those children as his. Thor would've acknowledged his children.